# VBScript, InputBox, variable place

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a script in VBS, which in brief, make a loop → <kbd>F5</kbd> in a page.

The script below:

```
Set  wsGin = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsInp = InputBox("Put a link", "Test", "Ex.: www.youtube.com.br/EXAMPLE")

wsGin.Run "chrome.exe wsInp"
WScript.Sleep 20000

Do
  wsGin.SendKeys "{F5}"      
  WScript.Sleep 4500
Loop
```

The problem and the question is:
The variable `wsInp` doesnt work when Chrome is started. Instead the variable works like a variable it works like itself "string". The result is:

```
http://wsinp/
```

And I'd like to see the current link already wrote at input.

Comment: `wsGin.Run "chrome.exe " & wsInp`

Comment: Dude, thank a lot, u have no idea how it was important to me!!